# How to simulate two processes sharing memory in gem5?

Tags: gem5

I want to simulate the situation where two processes have shared memory in gem5.

If it is a real machine test, I can use mmap, or doopen to achieve. But what should be done when using gem5 for simulation?

If it is a real machine test, I can use mmap, or doopen to achieve. But what should be done when using gem5 for simulation?

I tried it with mmap in gem5, but it didn't work as expected.

I wrote two programs.

program1:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "../util.h"
#define arr_len (64*8*8*8)
volatile  int test;
int main(){
    uint64_t *addr = (uint64_t *) mmap_file(0,"shared");
    int tt = time_mread(addr);
    mfence();
    int tt2 = time_mread(addr);
    printf("%p\n", addr);
    printf("time %d %d\n", tt,tt2);

    return 0;
}
```

program2:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "../util.h"

int main(){
    uint64_t *addr = (uint64_t *) mmap_file(0,"shared");
    uint64_t *synchronization = (uint64_t *)  mmap_file(64,"shared");
    delayloop(5000);
    int tt = time_mread(addr);
    printf("%p\n", addr);
    printf("time %d\n", tt);
    return 0;
}
```

util.h

```
#ifndef UTIL_H_
#define UTIL_H_

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>

#define PAGE_SHIFT 12
#define PAGEMAP_LENGTH 8
#define PAGE 4096
#define FILE_SIZE   4096


uint64_t rdtscp64() {
  uint32_t low, high;
  asm volatile ("rdtscp": "=a" (low), "=d" (high) :: "ecx");
  return (((uint64_t)high) << 32) | low;
}


uint64_t mmap_file(int offset, char *fileName)
{
    uint64_t addr;
    // Map file to virtual memory and extract the address at the file offset
    if (fileName != NULL) {
        int inFile = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
        if(inFile == -1) {
            printf("Failed to Open File\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        void *mapaddr = mmap(NULL,FILE_SIZE,PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED,inFile,0);
        if (mapaddr == (void*) -1 ) {
            printf("Failed to Map Address\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        addr = (uint64_t) mapaddr + offset;
    }
    return addr;
}

 int 
// Attribution: https://cs.adelaide.edu.au/~yval/Mastik/
time_mread(void *adrs) 
{
  volatile unsigned long time;

  asm volatile (
    // "lfence\n"
    "mfence\n"
    "rdtscp\n"
    "lfence\n"
    "mov %%eax, %%esi\n"
    "mov (%1), %%eax\n"
    "rdtscp\n"
    "sub %%esi, %%eax\n"
    : "=&a" (time)          // output
    : "r" (adrs)            // input
    : "ecx", "edx", "esi"); // clobber registers

  return (int) time;
}

 void mfence() {
  asm volatile("mfence");
}

 void delayloop(uint32_t cycles) {
  uint64_t start = rdtscp64();
  while ((rdtscp64()-start) < cycles)
    ;
}

#endif
```

In this function, two programs use mmap to map the location of the same file.

When the first program accesses it, it will bring this data into the cache. A shorter time is required on the second visit. Therefore, when the second program accesses the data at this location, it should be faster.

However the output is:
0x7ffff7e03000
time 291 22
0x7ffff7e03000
time 246

It can be seen that the first program requires 291 cycles for the first access, but 22 cycles for the second access. This also confirms that the cache line is in the cache, but the second program accessing the same location does not show a decrease in latency. This shows that they are not accessing the same data.

command is :

```
 /usr/local/src/gem5/build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=CacheAll,ExecAll,CacheBlock,LSQ --debug-file=/usr/local/src/gem5/runScripts/attack_spectre/trace.out --debug-start=168800000 /usr/local/src/gem5/configs/example/se.py --num-cpus=2 --l1d_replacement=LRU --mem-size=4GB --l1d_size=32kB --l1d_assoc=8 --l1i_size=32kB --l1i_assoc=4 --l2_assoc=16 --l2_size=2MB --caches --l2cache --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU -c '/usr/local/src/gem5/programs/spectre/sender;/usr/local/src/gem5/programs/spectre/receiver
```

What should I do? Does anyone know? thanks!!!

Comment: Does fs mode support all system calls?

Answer (score 0):

How to do this depends on if you're using FS or SE mode.

If you are using SE mode, gem5 processes have a function called map which will manually add a page table entry with a given virtual address and physical address. You can invoke this by calling process.map(VA= , PA=, size=) Note that this must be called after m5.instantiate in your config file. So you'd need to call this on each process. When you do this don't use mmap() as mmap will overwrite the PTE you manually added with process.map()

As for FS mode I'm not entirely sure. I'd imagine mmap or some other library would work!